# java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am new to spark and kafka. We have a requirement to integrate kafka+spark+Hbase(with Phoenix).

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars. The following servers require an updated phoenix.jar to be put in the classpath of HBase:

I ended up with the above ERROR. If anybody could you please help how to resolve this issue.

Below is error log:

> jdbc:phoenix:localhost.localdomain:2181:/hbase-unsecure
>       testlocalhost.localdomain:6667
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO Metrics: Initializing metrics system: phoenix
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-phoenix.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: phoenix metrics system started
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing master protocol: MasterService
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x161f6fc5e4800a3
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO ZooKeeper: Session: 0x161f6fc5e4800a3 closed
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
>   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars. The following servers require an updated phoenix.jar to be put in the classpath of HBase: region=SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1519831518459.b16e566d706c68469922eba74844a444., hostname=localhost,16020,1520282812066, seqNum=59
>       at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:476)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:150)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.checkClientServerCompatibility(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1272)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1107)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1429)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:2574)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:1024)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:212)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:358)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:341)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:339)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1492)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2437)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2382)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2382)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:149)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>       at com.spark.kafka.PhoenixJdbcClient.getConnection(PhoenixJdbcClient.scala:41)
>       at com.spark.kafka.PhoenixJdbcClient.currentTableSchema(PhoenixJdbcClient.scala:595)
>       at com.spark.kafka.SparkHBaseClient$.main(SparkHBaseClient.scala:47)
>       at com.spark.kafka.SparkHBaseClient.main(SparkHBaseClient.scala)
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
>   18/03/05 16:18:52 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.103:4040
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
>   18/03/05 16:18:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c8dd26fc-74dd-40fb-a339-8c5dda36b973

We are using *Amabri Server 2.6.1.3* with *HDP-2.6.3.0* and below components:

- Hbase-1.1.2
- kafka-0.10.1
- spark-2.2.0
- phoenix

Below are the POM artifact's I have added for HBase and Phoenix.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0-HBase-1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Comment: How have you attempted to fix the problem yourself?

Comment: I changed the title and improved your question formatting. Please put more effort in creating an easily readable question in the future.

Comment: I have seen some where (https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39449/phoenix-giving-outdated-jars-exception.html) as we need to copy Phoenix Server jar file to lib of HBase. I have done same but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following**
1.Copy Phoenix server jar to all HBase region servers(HBase lib folder)
2.Restart HBase master